# SQL Server 2012 generate scripts and import to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, concatenation

I want to copy a database from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008 R2 using "generate scripts".

Most of the DB is copied correctly, however I am having an issue with several procedures as the include `CONCAT` function in 2012 so I am getting the following error:

> 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

How can I handle this? The concat exists too many times for me to handle/change manually.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, `CONCAT` is a **new function** in SQL Server 2012 that just doesn't exist in SQL Server 2008 R2 - so you will **have to change it** - no matter how many times it occurs.....

Comment: It can only be changed manually.   There is no tool that I know of that can do it automatically.